# how to optimise my code?

Tags: java, data-structures

First line will contain two integers N and  M separated by a single space.
Next  lines will contain three integers  a,  b and k  separated by a single space.
N is length of sequence.
M is no of operations performed on that sequence.
a is the starting index from sequence and b is ending index from sequence, i have to add k to all elements in between a and k.(i have to do this M times on N length sequence)

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        int m=sc.nextInt();
        List l= new ArrayList(Collections.nCopies(n, 0));
        //System.out.println(l);

        for(int i=1;i<=m;i++){
            int a=sc.nextInt();
            int b=sc.nextInt();
            int k=sc.nextInt();
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                //if((a-j)<=b){
                if(j+1>=a && j+1<=b){
                    int ab= (int) l.get(j);
                    int sum=ab+k;
                    l.set(j,sum);
                }
            }
        }
        int total=0;
        total=(int) l.get(0);
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            int num=(int) l.get(i);
            if(num>total){
                total=num;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(total);
    }
}
```

Qyestion:
my code fails due to time out, and some other issues which im not aware of..please help to solve this or optimize my code.

Comment: oh. i have to find the maximum value of elements..from the sequence.

Comment: For one, you shouldn't use Raw Types with your `List`.  You wouldn't have to cast your `int` when pulling it back out.  Try `List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();` instead

Comment: Dont *expect* us to download your code, enter test data to see what is doing. Add such example information to your question. And beyond that "help me fix everything" is too unspecific. Ask specific questions please. And beyond that: you are participating in a **hacker** contest. Then heck; *hack* yourself. What is the point in asking other people solving *your* puzzle? The point of learning programming is to keep trying *yourself* until you succeed.

Comment: @CraigR8806 When talking about performance, using `List` isnt exactly great in the first place; as that implies boxing of int values into Integer objects; which is a costly operation. And I am also not sure if one really needs a dynamic list for all of this.

Comment: @GhostCat You're absolutely right.  I was merely **commenting** on the the poor choice of coding style.  This is why I did not generate an answer because my comment did not provide a solution for the stated question.

Comment: @GhostCat FYI i have completed my code and its working fine for small inputs. im not asking you to help me to arrive at a solution.im asking you to help me optimize it..

Comment: "Optimizing" is a **very** broad term. And beyond that: for working code, you should better turn to codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @CraigR8806 i have to use list in this ..i have no option.(My friends challenged me to use it)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of actually adding the same number in a range, you just add that number at `start` of the range and subtract the same after `end`. After all the operations the cumulative sum of this array will effectively be same as adding `k` to all elements in the given ranges. You can use this logic to solve this problem:

- Create an array of size n+2 or more:

  ```
  long arr[] = new long[n+2];
  ```
- for all the `m` operations (after reading the values of `a`, `b` and `k`), add `k` to `arr[a]` and subtract `k` from `arr[b+1]` :

  ```
  arr[a]+=k;
  arr[b+1]-=k;
  ```
- Now calculate cumulative sum of the above array and simultaneously calculate the maximum element like this:

  ```
  long mx = 0;
  for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
  {
       arr[i]+=arr[i-1];
       mx=Math.max(mx,arr[i]);
  }
  ```
- Now print the final answer which is `mx`.

Time complexity 
= time complexity for `m` O(1) operations (addition and subtraction at `a` and `b` respectively) + time complexity for cumulative sum
= O(m+n)

Hope this helps.

Comment: does your code also adds k to all elements in between a nd b?

Comment: Yes, effectively it does, after calculating the cumulative sum at the end

Comment: Kindly accept and upvote the answer if it solved your problem.